# How can I perform a simple file search in LaTeX?

Tags: folders

I'm looking to improve my `gitinfo` package by reducing the amount of setup needed.

For this, I want to be able to search for a file in the current directory, then the parent, then the grandparent ... until either (a) I find the file [OK] or (b) find a directory called `.git` [Error message a] or (c) fall off the top of the file system tree [Error message b].

I've tried nesting `\InputIfFileExists`, but that only gives me a fixed maximum number of levels.

Sorry, I really don't have a clue as to the simplest approach; so pointers to useful packages to use or copy would be a good option, rather than predigested answers (though these, obviously, would be very welcome).

---

Having done a little more reading, finding a directory might be a bit more difficult, so finding a file `.git/description` would do.

Comment: TeX is unable to find files without extension, I'm afraid: if no extension is supplied, TeX adds `.tex`. I believe this is doable with `pdftex` and `luatex`, but not with `xetex` unless shell escape is enabled. Checking whether we are at the top might be tougher, because Unix system allow `cd ..` when at the top.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I thought that no extension might prove problematic. I guess that the solution will have to be LuaTeX, but that's no good for a public package. Alternatively I can klugde just three levels and forget about the `.git` directory, but that's not what I call a quality solution. Thanks anyway...

Comment: With `pdftex` one can do `\pdffilemoddate` that expands to something if the file exists and to nothing if the file doesn't exist. The loop might end after a big, although finite, number of steps: 255 levels before reaching the top of the file system should be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works with `pdflatex` and `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcount\Brent@level
\newcommand\BrentInput[1]{%
  \Brent@level=\z@
  \def\Brent@prefix{}%
  \Brent@Input{#1}%
}
\def\Brent@Input#1{%
  \edef\Brent@temp{\pdf@filemoddate{\Brent@prefix/.git/description}}%
  \ifx\Brent@temp\@empty
    \advance\Brent@level\@ne
    % there's no .git/description file at this level
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {%
   \ifnum\Brent@level<255
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else
     \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
   {\InputIfFileExists{\Brent@prefix#1}{}
     {%
      % go up one level and retry
      \edef\Brent@prefix{../\Brent@prefix}%
      \Brent@Input{#1}%
     }%
   }
   {\errmessage{Too many levels}}
  }
  {\errmessage{.git found}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\BrentInput{file}

\BrentInput{foo}
\end{document}
```

I set a limit of 255 levels up from the current one. With XeLaTeX one has to rely on `-shell-escape`.

Since directories can't be found (at least with `\pdffilemoddate`), the `.git` directory must contain a file named `description`.

Comment: As always, thanks, @egreg . I'll have a play with this and see if I can break it (before it breaks me) :)